# Can we use Genetic Algorithm for selecting the optimal Network Model and Parameters?

Tags: genetic-algorithm, genetic

Can we use Genetic Algorithm for selecting the optimal network model and parameter? 
For example, can we use it to decide which will give the optimal performance among the following network structure and configuration:

```
 Network Types:

 -Convolutional Neural Network with auto encoder/decoder variants
 -Deep Neural Networks

Network Parameters:

-Learning Rate
-Momentum
-Number of hidden layers
-Number of hidden nodes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how widely this approach is used anymore, but to answer your question - Yes. It is possible to use a genetic algorithm to decide which network architecture is best suitable for a given problem.

You may want to look at this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220885651_Designing_Neural_Networks_using_Genetic_Algorithms). It talks about how you can use genetic algorithms to come up with the best network architecture.